# Are digital signatures from Mac's Preview app legally valid?

Tags: contract-law, signature, colorado

Mac's Preview application allows users to take a photo of their handwritten signature and convert it into a digital signature, which can then be inserted into PDF documents presumably in place of a handwritten signature. The signature Preview generates is not certified.

So, if someone "signs" a legal document by opening it in Preview and inserting their digital signature, is the signature valid?

Comment: It's going to depend on where you are in the world (i.e. what the laws of your state or country say), what type of document, and what legal effect you hope your signature to have.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The document in question is a wage demand letter from the Colorado Department of Labor and Employment (https://bit.ly/3gVhqKE), being sent to an employer based in Ohio. The letter is not a contract but I take it that it does have some legal force. Really, I'd like to ensure that the employer cannot discard the letter and suffer none of the elaborated penalties simply because it was signed via Preview.

Comment: @nbogs: as I heads up, I have added the "Colorado" and "contract-law" tags to your question, and removed the "jurisdiction" tag. When Trish said "this needs a jurisdiction tag", (to which multiple other people including myself agreed), what was meant was not (paradoxically enough) to add the tag labeled "jurisdiction"(which is for questions *about* the legal concept of jurisdiction), but rather add the tag for the legal region whose body of laws you wish to know about. Since you mentioned a Colorado department in your comment, I added the Colorado tag.